# How to drive this smartkey?

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, bus

Feel free to migrate this question if it does not suit SuperUser SE aim. It might be a topic for StackOverflow or Unix & Linux SE. Anyway, here I am...

I would like to interface a smartkey, lets say:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 073d:0025 Eutron S.p.a. SmartKey 3
```

An Eutron Smart Key. As far is I know, this key is working because I can use it and the bus recognize it. Going further:

```
$ sudo lsusb -s 002:008 -v
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 073d:0025 Eutron S.p.a. SmartKey 3
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               1.10
  bDeviceClass          255 Vendor Specific Class
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0         8
  idVendor           0x073d Eutron S.p.a.
  idProduct          0x0025 SmartKey 3
  bcdDevice            1.31
  iManufacturer           3 EUTRON
  iProduct                1 SmartKey 3
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           18
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          0 
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower               20mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           0
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

Then I looked to `dmesg` output and related events by listening to:

```
$ tail /var/log/syslog
kernel: [ *] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
kernel: [ *] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=073d, idProduct=0025
kernel: [ *] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
kernel: [ *] usb 2-1.2: Product: SmartKey 3
kernel: [ *] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: EUTRON
mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2"
mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 8 was not an MTP device
```

I can see that Media Transfer Protocol is not native for this kind of hardware, but nothing happens then. No other decision is taken by the kernel. If I go deeper, I can see that default driver is in use, but it does not help:

```
$ lspci -v 
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0492
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at e2e50000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
```

So, I am wondering how can I figure out:

- what should be the correct driver (no match on internet using IDs, does it exist for debian? I know there is some trickery for windows, but this is not the purpose) to drive the key properly?
- and then, what would be the interface file?